# Selenium Python xpath contains and sibling question

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use python selenium to select users on a webpage and open the link to their profile. Below is the repeating HTML for every user on the webpage:

```
<div class="w-50-ns w-100 ph1">
    <div class="w-100 br1 pointer bg-animate hover-bg-dark-primary bg-near-black" onclick="openLink(event, '/users/0000')">
        <div class="pv2 pr3 pl2 mb2 br1">
            <div class="flex items-center pa1">
                <div class="flex-auto mw-100">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <div class="flex-none flex items-center">
                            <a class="relative overflow-hidden dib mr3-ns mr2 link" data-tippy-theme="lighter small" href="/users/0000" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img class="db ipp br1 object-cover" src="https://" width="70" height="70">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relative flex-auto mw-100 mw-none-ns" style="max-height: 58px; top: -1px;">
                            <div class="lh-copy truncate silver">
                                <a class="link span f5 fw7 secondary" href="/users/0000">UserName</a>
                                &nbsp;
                                <span class="f6 fw7 silver">AgeSex Category</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="f6 lh-copy fw4 silver nowrap truncate">Los Angeles, California</div>
                            <div class="relative pd1 f6 fw4 lh-copy mid-gray nowrap truncate">
                                <a class="link gray hover-silver" href="/users/0000/pictures"># pics</a>
                                &nbsp;·&nbsp;
                                <a class="link gray hover-silver" href="/users/0000/posts"># posts</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="tr">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the main part that I'm looking at though. I'm trying to check if the AgeSex, ie 19F or 20M, matches a selected range and sex and if it does than click on the user's profile link above it

```
                    <div class="lh-copy truncate silver">
                        <a class="link span f5 fw7 secondary" href="/users/0000">UserName</a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <span class="f6 fw7 silver">AgeSex Category</span>
                    </div>
```

I tried:

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., '18F') or contains(., '20M')])/preceding-sibling::class[ @name = 'link span f5 fw7 secondary']").click()

self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), '18F') or contains(text(), '20M')])/preceding-sibling::class[ @name = 'link span f5 fw7 secondary']").click()
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
actions.move_to_element(element, 0, 0).perform()
TypeError: move_to_element() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I'm new to this so I have no idea if I'm even going in the right direction and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could perform a click using the following command:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., '18F') or contains(., '20M')]/preceding-sibling::a[@class = 'link span f5 fw7 secondary']").click()
```

Here some notes:

1. For preceding-sibling the syntax is preceding-sibling::{xPath} --> preceding-sibling::tagname[@attibute='value']
2. I recommend you use `find_element_by xpath` (singular) instead of `find_elements_by_xpath` (plural), because the latest returns a list, which has no `click()` function. If there are more than one elements you want to click, use `find_elements_by_xpath` to make a list of them and then iterate over them to click the preceding sibling of each one of them.

For example:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., '18F') or contains(., '20M')]")
for elem in elems:
    elem.find_element_by_xpath("./preceding-sibling::a[@class = 'link span f5 fw7 secondary']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with it today and found how to open the url of a single AgeSex:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains (.,'23F')]").click();
```

I decided to go another route and instead of clicking on an element make a list of all the urls.

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains (.,'30F')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]").get_attribute('href')
```

The above is only a single AgeSex though, so I have to write it out for every option. If one didn't exist it would throw an error so I wrote a try and except block for each one:

```
try:
  if self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains (.,'27F')]").is_displayed():
    user27 = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains (.,'27F')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]").get_attribute('href')
    if user27 not in urls:
      urls.append(user27)
except:
  pass
```

If attribute exist it adds the href to the list.

I feel like there has to be a lot better way of writing this. A way that's more efficient and doesn't require 10-15 try and except blocks